# How to fix command out of Sync on php mysqli_multi_query?

Tags: php

I have a hard time fixing this problem. I used multiple query because of my system functionality. I have a delivery table with 2 query that needs to insert on 2 table from database. I can insert only one table row but when 2 or more data to be inserted, the command out of sync show.

Below is my graphical.

[image]

This is the PHP code I used.

```
 if($result == true){
            for($count = 0; $count<count($_POST['barcode']); $count++){
                        $transaction[] = $transaction_no;
            }
            for($num= 0; $num < count($_POST['barcode']); $num++){
                $transaction1   = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $transaction[$num]);
                $barcode_1      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $barcode[$num]);
                $product_1      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $product[$num]);
                $qty_1          = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $qty[$num]);
                $buy_price_1    = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $buy_price[$num]);
                $unit_1         = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $unit[$num]);
                $tax_1          = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $tax[$num]);
                $min_qty_1      = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $min_qty[$num]);
                $sell_price_1   = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $sell_price[$num]);

                $query = "SELECT product_no,quantity FROM products WHERE product_no='$barcode_1'";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)>0){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
                        $newqty = $row['quantity'] + $qty_1;
                        $query1 = "UPDATE products SET quantity = $newqty WHERE product_no = '$barcode_1";
                        mysqli_query($db, $query1);
                    }
                }else{
                    $insert .= "
                    INSERT INTO products(product_no,product_name,sell_price,quantity,unit,min_stocks) 
                    VALUES('$barcode_1','$product_1',$sell_price_1,$qty_1,'$unit_1',$min_qty_1);
                        ";

                    $insert1 .= "
                    INSERT INTO product_delivered(transaction_no,product_id,total_qty,buy_price,tax_rate)
                    VALUES('$transaction1','$barcode_1',$qty_1,$buy_price_1,$tax_1);
                    ";
                }
            }

        if($insert != ''){
            if(mysqli_multi_query($db,$insert)){
                echo "Item Inserted";
            }else{
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
        if($insert1 != ''){
            mysql_next_result($db);
            if(mysqli_multi_query($db,$insert1)){
                echo "Item Inserted";
            }else{
                echo "Error";
            }
```

I did not show all my code because only the $insert1 got an error. I tried the

> mysqli_next_result()

before the 2nd query but it only work for two queries. The problem showed when I inserted 3+ queries. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did I understand right that you are trying to run mysqli_query() one time with multiple statements? If so, that is not gonna work, you'll have to call mysqli_query() multiple times instead.

Comment: I used mysqli_multi_query(). I believe its possible for mutliple statement.